# Lightdm multiseat problem on debian

Tags: systemd, d-bus, lightdm

I have a problem with multiseat and lightdm, problem is somehow with systemd and dbus, but if I have all setup correctly and setup dbus with allow setting for everything, I always get permission denied (this is from dbus monitor with debuggin):

```
method call time=1562850404.807597 sender=:1.1 -> destination=org.freedesktop.login1 serial=3 path=/org/freedesktop/login1; interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Manager; member=ListSeats
error time=1562850404.811954 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.1 error_name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed reply_serial=3
   string "Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.login1: Permission denied"
```

Here is a part from dbus config:

```
 <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.login1"
           send_interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager"
           send_member="ListSeats"/>
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks!